# Assigning values to member of structures using void pointer and offset calculated

Tags: c, structure, offset, void

I am trying to assign the values to members of a structure within a function which accepts the void * as an argument and then fill the data values based on the offset calculated for the  members of structure.

```
 typedef struct
    {
       char C_BFR_LINK[1];
       char C_TABLE_DATA[1];
       double MF_COD_BALANCE;
       char C_TYPE_DT[1];
    }ANS;
```

The Function

```
void fillin( void *pp)  
{  

 double* FVAR;  
 char* CVAR;  
 CVAR = pp;  
 memcpy(CVAR,"I",1);  
 CVAR = (void *)(pp + 1);  
 memcpy(CVAR,"S",1);  
 FVAR = (void *)(pp + 2);  
 *FVAR = 234.96;  
 CVAR = (void *) (pp + 10);  
  memcpy(CVAR,"Z",1);  
  return ;   
}
```

is responsible to fill in the values at respective offsets 1, 2, and 10.

I am calling this function within main as below
**

```
int main()  
 {  
   void* p ;
  ANS ans;  
  fillin(&ans);  
  return 0;  
 }
```

**

I debugged using gdb that within the function **fillin** the values gets assigned to the members but as soon as the **control comes to the main program the double value is lost** and it's not proper.

```
(gdb) p pp
$1 = (void *) 0xffffdabc    
(gdb) x /c 0xffffdabc  
0xffffdabc:     73 'I'  
(gdb) x /c 0xffffdabd    
0xffffdabd:     83 'S'  
(gdb) n  
32       *FVAR = 234.96;  
(gdb) n  
33      CVAR = (void *) (pp + 10);  
(gdb) **x /f 0xffffdabe**  
0xffffdabe:     234.96000000000001  
57       return 0;  
(gdb) **p ans**  
$2 = {C_BFR_LINK = "I", C_TABLE_DATA = "S",  
  **MF_COD_BALANCE = 1.9876540305898699e-268**, C_TYPE_DT = "\213"}
```

Can Anyone help me out? This code is being built with gcc 4.4.6 20120305. Any pointers or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't do this. Your code assumes a lot of things that are not true, you cannot compute struct member offsets manually and be right since the compiler can insert padding for alignment purposes. Use `offsetof` if you must. Also, your casting to `(void *)` on the right-hand side does nothing. You should have been getting compiler warnings for this, pointer arithmetic on `void *` isn't very nice.

Comment: Thanks unwind for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone else already mentioned this is a very bad idea, however, if you pack the struct to avoid padding and use a `char *` and `sizeof()` you might be able to get away with it, example:

```
typedef struct {
   char C_BFR_LINK[1];
   char C_TABLE_DATA[1];
   double MF_COD_BALANCE;
   char C_TYPE_DT[1];
}__attribute__((__packed__)) ANS;

void fillin( void *pp)  
{  
    char* CVAR = pp;
    double FVAR = 234.96;
    /* sizeof(char) is always one */
    memcpy(CVAR, "I", sizeof(char));  
    CVAR += sizeof(char);
    memcpy(CVAR, "S", sizeof(char));  
    CVAR += sizeof(char);
    memcpy(CVAR, &FVAR, sizeof(double));
    CVAR += sizeof(double);
    memcpy(CVAR,"Z",1);  
}  
int main()  
{  
    ANS ans;  
    fillin(&ans);  
    printf("%c\n", ans.C_BFR_LINK[0]);
    printf("%c\n", ans.C_TABLE_DATA[0]);
    printf("%c\n", ans.C_TYPE_DT[0]);
    printf("%f\n", ans.MF_COD_BALANCE);
    return 0;  
}
```

This prints:

```
I
S
Z
234.960000
```

Note: This won't work on architectures which does *not* support unaligned memory access, and possibly other problems I'm not aware of, therefore, a more portable way to do it is to let the compiler pad the structure and use `offsetof` macro as suggested by other answers, which evaluates to the offset of a member from the beginning of the struct, example:

```
#define offsetof(type, member)  __builtin_offsetof (type, member)
CVAR + offsetof(ANS, C_BFR_LINK); //evaluates to 0
CVAR + offsetof(ANS, C_TABLE_DATA); //evaluates to 1
CVAR + offsetof(ANS, MF_COD_BALANCE); //evaluates to 8
CVAR + offsetof(ANS, C_TYPE_DT); //evaluates to 16
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mux, I was not aware of the "__attribute__((__packed__))".

Comment: Of course, if you have the "right" (or "wrong", depending on how you see it) processor architecture when you use this, it will crash - e.g. Sparc, Mips processors won't like reading data that isn't aligned properly - so you wouldn't be able to run this code on those processors). I personally think this is NOT a good solution [and of course, it doesn't work in anywhere near all compilers 0- as far as I know, only `gcc` supports this particular form - other compilers usually have a way of achieving the same, but it's very hard to make portable]

Comment: @MatsPetersson I completely agree, but AFAIK this is the only way to make this code work without using `offsetof`, assuming an architecture where unaligned memory access is allowed it will just just slow things down, I've added a note anyway.

Comment: Yes, my point is that "not allowing the compiler to align the data as it wishes" is making the code very un-portable and quite likely slower than it should be. You can of course write your own variant of "offsetof", but that's a waste of time if there already is one there.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will add "padding" to align some types in your structure. The amount of padding depends on the compiler, what processor you compile for, what compiler settings are used, etc, etc.

As mentioned by "unwind", there are macros provided to calculate the offset into a structure, `offsetof(type, member)`, which "does the right thing". Your code stuffs a float into the "nomansland" (padding) between your two char variables and the actual float variable, which is why you are getting "random" results [obviously not completely random - just "not what you expect" - it's entirely predictable if you know the difference in offset and figure out the bit-pattern of the floating point value that this provides].

Answer (score 0):

Compile with warnings

```
CVAR = (void *)(pp + 1);
```

This gives you  `warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic`

```
FVAR = (void *)(pp + 2);  
*FVAR = 234.96;  
CVAR = (void *) (pp + 10);
```

Assuming `sizeof(double) == 8` is not a good idea

Comment: Thanks David for prompt answer. Yes it turned out to be structure padding issue.